# SQL Server: Local Query Time vs. Network Query Time... and Locks

Tags: sql-server, locking

Querying from a view into a temp table can insert 800K records in < 30 seconds. However, querying from the view to my app across the network takes 6 minutes. Does the server build the dataset and then send it, releasing any locks acquired after the dataset is built?  Or are the locks held for that entire 6 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the server build the dataset and then send it, releasing any locks acquired after the dataset is built?

If you're using READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT or are in SNAPSHOT isolation then there are no row and page locks in the first place.

Past that depends a on whether it's a streaming query plan or not.  With a streaming plan SQL Server may be reading slowly from the tables as the results are sent across the network.